How to properly use Nginx as reverse proxy with ssl for MySQL?
Nginx as reverse proxy without ssl works fine Nginx reverse proxy for mysql without ssl, however when I enable ssl, no more connections can be established. Ssl certificate is issued to lets say my.domain.
My configuration:
stream {
    log_format main '$remote_addr - [$time_local] $status';

    upstream demo-db {
        server 127.0.0.1:3300;
    }

    server {
        listen 6030 ssl so_keepalive=on;
        server_name my.domain; # no change when this line is removed
        access_log /var/log/nginx/demo.db.log main;

        ssl_certificate <hidden>;
        ssl_certificate_key <hidden>;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;

        proxy_socket_keepalive on;

        proxy_pass demo-db;
    }
}

I get 500 status in access log:
<ip> - [14/Aug/2024:11:57:16 +0200] 500

Nothing in error log.
When I do https request in Postman https://my.domain:6030, I get this error: Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response - Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
My mysql client DBeaver shows this error (with and without using ssl in DBeaver connection configuration):
Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

details:
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Is there more configuration to be done in order to make ssl work?

If you have access to nginx config and can reload it, then you probably have root access. Why don't you just change bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in mysqld.conf? Meanwhile, SSL is managed by MySQL server.

@IgorPopov potential load balancing, logging, baning and other tcp configuration before mysql.

Nginx listen ssl parameter allows specifying that all connections accepted on this port should work in SSL mode to handle HTTPS requests. That's not what you actually need.
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen
While we just need secure connections to MySQL proxied with Nginx.
Here is a simple Nginx configuration for your case.
stream {
  upstream demo_db {
    server 127.0.0.1:3306;
  }
  server {
    listen 6030;
    proxy_pass demo_db;
    zone tcp_mem 64k;
  }
}

Also, you need to configure MySQL server to accept encrypted connections.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html
Let's assume you already have your certificate.
mysqld.conf:
[mysqld]
ssl_ca=ca.pem
ssl_cert=server-cert.pem
ssl_key=server-key.pem
require_secure_transport=ON # require ONLY secure connections


It works flawlessly now even without configuring ssl pem certificates (mysql uses generated defaults). What is zone tcp_mem 64k;? It seems to be an extra.

@Wortig https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#zone It defines the name and size of the shared memory zone that keeps the group’s configuration and run-time state that are shared between worker processes.
